# HTML5 FileReader output to D3.js chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to use a local CSV file to populate my D3.js pie chart. The CSV file simply consists of

```
label,count
Monday,379130
Tuesday,424923
Wednesday,430728
Thursday,432138
Friday,428295
Saturday,368239
Sunday,282701
```

The d3.js chart is the simple pie chart explained here at ZeroViscosity:

http://zeroviscosity.com/d3-js-step-by-step/step-4-loading-external-data

So far I have,

```js
 (function(d3) {
   ...
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file_input" accept=".csv"/>
    <div id="output_field"></div>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/read-csv.js"></script>

    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I'm not sure how to get the data and then pass this on to the chart. How would I set this up?

Comment: So, where's the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use file API to load the file as data URL. See [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). Then, it can used like before `d3.csv(url, ...)`:

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      drawChart(e.target.result);
    };
  })(file);

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

document.getElementById('file_input').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

function drawChart(url) {
  var width = 360;
  var height = 360;
  var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  var donutWidth = 75;
  var legendRectSize = 18;
  var legendSpacing = 4;
  var color = d3.scale.category20b();
  var svg = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +
      ',' + (height / 2) + ')');

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
    .outerRadius(radius);

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.count;
    })
    .sort(null);

  d3.csv(url, function(error, dataset) { // NEW
    dataset.forEach(function(d) { // NEW
      d.count = +d.count; // NEW
    }); // NEW
    var path = svg.selectAll('path')
      .data(pie(dataset))
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
        return color(d.data.label);
      });

    var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
      .data(color.domain())
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend')
      .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
        var offset = height * color.domain().length / 2;
        var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;
        var vert = i * height - offset;
        return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
      });
    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('width', legendRectSize)
      .attr('height', legendRectSize)
      .style('fill', color)
      .style('stroke', color);

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
      .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d;
      });
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file_input" accept=".csv" />
<div id="output_field"></div>

<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I was trying to load it as text for the longest time >.<